# Broken Axis - Excel Charts

Tags: excel

I'm looking for a chart that allows me to have non-consistent axis to better capture outliers.

Something similar to below

[image]

The y-axis range varies quite a bit. I wanted a more elegant solution than what I did -- I superimposed two graphs, with the graph on top pulling its own range. I had to manually align the graphs so that they overlapped.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it isn't a built-in type you need to find a work around. You seem to have a found a good work around. If you do this sort of thing a lot, you could write a VBA macro which will automatically separate your data into separate ranges for graphing and handle the formatting and chart alignment.